# how to use mysql_num with somfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I know its a very silly question but having issues with symfony and doctrine createQuery..

I need an array result like this way to feed my chart app:

```
array (size=6)
0 => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Firefox' (length=7)
  1 => float 45
1 => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'IE' (length=2)
  1 => float 26.8
2 => 
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Chrome' (length=6)
  1 => float 12.8
```

and im using this query:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
     'SELECT c.status, COUNT (c.status) FROM MyAppBundle:Content c GROUP BY c.status '
 );

 $results = $query->getArrayResult();
```

but its returning like this:

```
array (size=4)
0 => 
array (size=2)
  'status' => string 'Converted' (length=9)
  1 => string '4359' (length=4)
1 => 
array (size=2)
  'status' => string 'Received Q' (length=10)
  1 => string '277' (length=3)
2 => 
array (size=2)
  'status' => string 'Signed' (length=6)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
3 => 
array (size=2)
  'status' => string 'Uploaded' (length=8)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
```

Now in regular php and mysql:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_NUM)){
      $results[] = $row ;
}
```

can return the array result as expected but my q is how can i do it with symfony2 and doctrine way?

Comment: You already have an array from `doctrine`. What else do you need?

Comment: but you see the difference in return? i need the same return so that my chart can work.

Comment: I have no idea how `Converted` can be changed to `Firefox` but you can try old plain `foreach ($results ...`

Comment: you dont understand, i dont need to change that, i need 'status' to be chnaged to '0" i dont need status key i need 0 there

Comment: What happens if you modify your query to `'SELECT c.status, COUNT (c.status) + 0 FROM MyAppBundle:Content c GROUP BY c.status '`?

Answer (score 0):

You can give your arrays numeric indexes by using `array_values`

```
foreach($results as &$result) {
    $result = array_values($result);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but one q the numbers are returning as string, how can i make it float ?

Comment: ok finally i did this..

 $results = $query->getArrayResult();
     $datas = array();
     $values = array();


     foreach($results as &$result) {
         $result['total'] = (float) $result['total'];
         $datas[] = $result;
     }

     foreach($datas as &$data) {

         $data = array_values($data);
         $values[] = $data;
     }

     return $values;


    }

but is it a good solution?